How to reguralize the building footprint with FME
I extracted the building footprint with from LAS Dataset in FME, but I could not find a Transformer who can straighten the outline of the buildings after the FME sequence (see capture).
The equivalent of the tool I'm looking for is called "Reguralize Building Footprint" in ArcGis Pro.
Is there an equivalent tool in FME?
FME sequence
I tried to use the following sequence sequence that inspired me found on this website:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172259/creating-building-footprints-from-las-files
but the result was not convincing
then I tried my sequence which was inspired by the first one but simpler, the result was more convincing but the outline of the buildings are not straight. From what I understand, the hull accumulator is supposed to straighten the contours of buildings, but it didn't respect their original shape so I removed it.
output shapefile obtained with my sequence
